# How to make the UserProfile Info availlable on a block

Tags: users

I understand how to preprocess a specific block to make some variable available for that it, but what I don't understand is where I grab these variable that I want to be available in my  block.

I have the following code:

```
function THEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    $variables['user_profile']= $user_profile; 
}
```

`$user_profile` is `NULL`.

So in other terms what i would like is to grab all the data entered by a user during the registration and make it available within block under for instance a user_profile variable.
Is it possible at all?

---

Well i tried but it doesn't seem to do anything in drupal 7. Also isn't the user variable holding data only for the current loged in user ? I would like to retrieve the data of any user in order to populate the profile page with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct snipet:

```
function THEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    $variables['user_profile'] = menu_get_object('user');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the global user object to get info about the currently logged in user, then pass that user object to [profile_load_profile](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--profile--profile.module/function/profile_load_profile/6):

```
function THEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    global $user;
    $user_profile = profile_load_profile($user); 
    $variables['user_profile']= $user_profile; 
}
```

(code is untested but should work)